# UILabel textColor property marked as nonnull, but comment as nil by default

Tags: swift, uilabel

In the Apple class of `UILabel`

```
open class UILabel : UIView, NSCoding, UIContentSizeCategoryAdjusting {


    open var text: String? // default is nil

    open var font: UIFont! // default is nil (system font 17 plain)

    open var textColor: UIColor! // default is nil (text draws black)
```

but what totaly confuses me, is that `font` and `textColor` are marked as ! so they cannot be `nil` (or else crash), but the comment states

```
default is nil
```

am i missing smth. or not understand smth. proper, or is this some documentation fault or the var is assigned wrong with ! and should have had ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in playground

```
import UIKit

let label = UILabel()
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 45)
print(label.font)

label.font = nil
print(label.font)
```

This will be result:

```
Optional(<UICTFont: 0x7ff122c059d0> font-family: ".SFUIDisplay"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 45.00pt)
Optional(<UICTFont: 0x7ff122e04390> font-family: ".SFUIText"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt)
```

Optional seems and in my humble opinion is only the tool for setting the default value. Imagine scenario when it is not an optional. There would be no easy way to set it back. If it would be in Swift I bet it would look something like this:

```
class Label {
    var font: UIFont! = nil {
        //Set some default font in here 
        didSet { if font == nil { font =  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)} }
    }
}
```